# If $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{c}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}$, then $\mathbf{a}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{b}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How do we prove the following?

**Claim.** *Let $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b}, \mathbf{c}$ be non-zero vectors. If $\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{c}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}$, then $\mathbf{a}$ is parallel to $\mathbf{b}$.*

(**Definition.** The vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$ are *parallel* if  $\mathbf{u}=k\mathbf{v}$ for some $k\neq0$.)

Comment: You can't, because it is false. Take any three non-parallel coplanar vectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true in general. One counterexample is $a=i,\,b=i+j,\,c=j$.